# How to obtain Spring library to set up Spring environment?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have been trying to start a simple Spring project as a part of my study. From the tutorials (they are about a year old resources i am refering), it seems the Spring related libraries were easily available online then. But now; I was unable to get something like a "spring_ver_no.zip" from the spring source site. It is having options to download a tool suite which is about 350 MBs large.
Can you please guide me if that download is the way to setup a Spring development environment?If not what is the way to set up a simple Spring environment in eclipse.

Thanks
Angie

Comment: have you tried this: http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Answer (score 2):

You should use a dependency management tool like Gradle or Maven, and let this tool download the libraries for you. See [the quick start](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/#quick-start) for how to include Spring in your dependencies. If you still want to download the jar files and add them manually to your project, then download them directly from the Maven central repository: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.springframework%22

Spring is, for a long time, splitted in several modules. You have to download all the modules you need.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is using Maven lately. You should use it too. Maven is a build tool and dependency manager that will ease your life.